# Logic to add dependencies in ivy.xml for a Qmetry framework Project to automate Mobile native apps

Tags: java, mobile, appium, qaf

I am trying to understand a project based on QAF. It uses ANT for managing dependencies along with Apache IVY. While going through the ivy.xml, I saw these dependencies added in the ivy.xml.

```
<dependency org="com.qmetry" name="qaf" rev="2.1.14" force="true"/>
<dependency org="com.qmetry" name="qaf-support" rev="2.1.14-RC2" />
<dependency org="com.qmetry" name="qaf-support-ws" rev="latest.integration" />
<dependency org="com.qmetry" name="qaf-support-mobile" rev="latest.integration" />
```

Questions:
On searching online for "qaf-support-mobile" to find the Maven dependency, there are no search results for the same? 
But still this dependency exists in ivy.xml & it works fine. What does this imply?

Answer (score 1):

Qaf support mobile is for pre defined mobile steps. It is optional dependency deployed in GitHub but not in maven central.

For mobile automation you need to make sure to add appium dependency in your project (if not adding qaf-support-mobile dependency).

```
<dependency org="io.appium" name="java-client" rev="latest.integration"/>
```

It will enable you to do mobile app test automation using appium with all qaf features. Refer [FAQ](
https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/how_to_run_on_native_app_on_appium.html).

Comment: Can you share links to online info on this? like, what dependencies we need to add to test Mobile native apps? What's the advantage of adding these dependencies? Is there any specific order we need to add those dependencies?

Comment: Thanks! I have seen that document. It will be of great help, if you can point me to a link with more details.